# How do I make a transparent desktop icon (like the Firefox icon)

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

[image]

I have this icon converted into a .ico

When I change a desktop folder to this icon, the four outer corners are white, and not see through. An example of an icon I'm trying to replicate would be like Firefox, where it is round and the there are no edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your image have an alpha channel? You posted a JPEG file on your question. Is this the image you are trying to convert?  If so, you'll need the image with transparency in the first place saved in a different format that supports it, like PNG. Example:

[image]

The JPEG format does not store an alpha channel and thus does not have transparency.